# Can one delete own comment in chatroom? Can owner of chat-room delete chat-room?

Tags: support, chat

2 question about chat-room:
Can one delete own comment in chatroom?
Can owner of chat-room delete  chat-room?
Thank you

Comment: meta.SE: [How do you delete a room on chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57099/how-do-you-delete-a-room-on-chat)

Comment: Based on this feature request, I'd guess that ordinary user cannot deleted their messages: [Allow owner of message to delete them in chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80082/allow-owner-of-message-to-delete-them-in-chat).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The links given by Martin Sleziak answer both questions.

1. Room owners cannot delete the room. Rooms are frozen automatically  after 15 days of inactivity; a frozen room with few messages is subsequently deleted. See [How do you delete a room on chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57099/how-do-you-delete-a-room-on-chat).
2. A user can delete a chat message only during 2 minutes after it was posted. If there is a good reason for the message to be deleted, the user should either (i) ping a moderator, or (ii) flag for moderator attention. Generally, (i) is preferable to (ii) because flags propagate across all Stack Exchange chat rooms (except those attached to SO and meta.SE) which gives your request a bit more publicity than you wanted. Room owners cannot delete messages, but they can move them to another room. See: [Allow owner of message to delete them in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80082/allow-owner-of-message-to-delete-them-in-chat).

Comment: I see the user that originally posted this answer has deleted their account, obviously because of the outrage that #2 means that if you post a comment in a thread that is subsequently moved to chat against your wishes, you have no recourse to delete your comment like you could have if it had not been moved to chat.